# What is Windows PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

What is PowerShell?

I have Windows 7 installed, and I noticed that it has PowerShell. I remember installing this a while back when signing up for Microsoft Azure, but only because it was required.

What would the explanation be in layman's terms?

Answer (score 55):

PowerShell is a new command shell and scripting language for Windows.  It is cool for a lot of reasons:

**The language is sane**, especially when compared to CMD.

**Scripts and command line share a language**.  CMD had many small but important differences.  CScript and Windows Scripting Host are not interpreted.

**Command line usage can be quick while scripts can be readable**, thanks to the combination of aliases and smart command argument processing.  For example, `dir -r .` is the same as `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "."`

**Consistent command argument syntax**, across **all** cmdlets and custom scripts (in V2.0).

**Powerful interaction with other technologies**, most notably .NET. Also, WMI is suddenly convenient and accessible. COM is there, too. [V2 makes Win32 interop easy](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/PowerShellPInvokeWalkthrough.aspx), too.

**An integrated script editor/interactive shell** in V2 that is very cool.

**Command pipelines work on objects, not strings**, which means you don't need to parse, and you can format text for humans not the next command.  In bash I did a lot of `cut`, but in PowerShell I don't have to.  The objects are real .NET objects, which is very powerful.

Before PowerShell I managed to become an expert in CMD script writing, but now I can start erasing that part of my brain.  Thank goodness.

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that lots of Microsoft products are adding PowerShell support, especially for server products. For example, Exchange ships with PowerShell cmdlets, so you can administer your Exchange server via PowerShell.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Where the resources that you used to learn about powershell?

Comment: 1) Objects is a concept new for many.  One should not forgot that a string is just a certain type of object. 2) Exchange 2007 is an excellent example, it doesn't just ship with PowerShell, but the entire admin UI is built *on* PowerShell.  Not all Microsoft products have that level of integration.

Comment: @Click: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973757(VS.85).aspx, http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528492/, http://www.manning.com/payette/.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, the big deal is PowerShell passes around objects.  It takes a while to realize just how powerful this is.  For example, instead of munging the text output of a utility, looking for what you want in characters 7 through 18, you can just access a property of an object.  That's much faster to use, and it's not going to break if a new version adds an extra character to the output.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft PowerShell is Microsoft's new commandline utility that was designed to provide greater control and flexibility to IT administrators.

You can think of it as a really complicated version of the command prompt designed for repeatable tasks.

[From Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx):

> Microsoft Windows PowerShell command line shell and scripting language helps IT professionals achieve greater control and productivity. Using a new admin-focused scripting language, more than 130 standard command line tools, and consistent syntax and utilities, Windows PowerShell allows IT professionals to more easily control system administration and accelerate automation. Windows PowerShell is easy to adopt, learn, and use, because it works with your existing IT infrastructure and existing script investments, and because it runs on Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows Server 2003. Windows PowerShell is now included as part of Windows Server 2008 and can be evaluated in Windows Server 2008 Beta 3. Exchange Server 2007, System Center Operations Manager 2007, System Center Data Protection Manager V2, and System Center Virtual Machine Manager also leverage Windows PowerShell to improve administrator control, efficiency, and productivity.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the cool effects of the .NET integration / object hangling: calling [webservices from the command line](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!512.entry) and handling the results as .NET objects that can be manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

The value of PowerShell is less a benefit for end-users, and much more a benefit for system maintainers, because they know it will be installed on every machine that has Windows 7 or later.

Answer (score 1):

**What is it for?**

Powershell is great for getting a degree of control over your computer that you don’t normally have. It's for Windows users.

**How do I use it?**

If you have Windows 7 or beyond, Powershell comes installed with your system. If you have anything before Windows 7 (Vista and XP), then it is recommended to update your windows. Once you are able to find Powershell in your start menu, you’re ready to go!

**How is it different from the regular Command Prompt?**

If you’re a Mac or Linux user, you’ve probably used other command-line interfaces before. In fact, if you’re a Linux user you’ve Definitely used it. This is what’s known as a Unix command-line interface, and it’s not the same as Powershell, so most of the commands for a Unix system won’t work in Powershell. It’s a totally different system than the one that you’re used to.

**Is there anything I should know before starting to use it?**

You should learn some of the commands to use it. You can get a list of basic commands from here: [Introduction to PowerShell: Learn to use Commands & Scripts](https://erainnovator.com/introduction-to-powershell/)

**Any awesome things you can do with it that a super user should know about?**

The scripts that you will write and execute in Powershell are .ps1 scripts, and they are generally simpler than scripts like Java or Python. These scripts are used to execute simple, usually automated tasks for your computer to follow. The limits of what the script can do are limited by the abilities of Powershell itself.

Answer (score 0):

Windows PowerShell is a task automation and configuration management framework from Microsoft.

It's having extendable command shell and scripting language which can be used to manage or administer server environments like Windows Server, [Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server) and also [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) 2010.

Answer (score -3):

PowerShell is Bash with more annoying syntax.

Comment: Don't hate, you know it's true!