# how to read and print version number from a file on network location using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file named \network_location\files\build_ver.txt on a network location which has the build version stored.
Lets say 1029,
I want to read this through a batch file and print it..

Any suggestion on:

**1**. How to read the build_ver from the text file on the network location
   **2**. Print the read build_Ver

Comment: Do you have access to [Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514492/what-is-windows-powershell)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
set $NetPath="x:\network_location\files\build_ver.txt" 

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type %$NetPath%') do set $Ver=%%a
echo %$Ver%
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to read from a file is to use the `set` command with the `/p` switch. Like so:

```
set /p version=<\\network_location\files\build_ver.txt
echo %version%
```

Note that this will grab the first line of `build_ver.txt`, whereas sachadee's answer will grab the last line (which *can* cause problems if there is a newline in the file, resulting in an empty variable).

Comment: does it not really work with UNC paths?i just tried and it works

Comment: Oops, so it does, my bad. Thanks.